# The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, formatexception

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the page that you would like to set the bookmark on: ");
    SetBookmarkPage(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine));
```

It's the int.Parse(string) part that gives me the error message of the topic of this thread. Don't really understand what I should do, I'm parsing a string into an int and sending it with the SetBookmarkPage method, what am I missing?
SetBookmarkPage looks like this and is contained in the same class:

`private void SetBookmarkPage(int newBookmarkPage) {}`

Comment: sigh... missed a few parenthesis..
I blame tiredness and VS for not completing parenthesis like Netbeans does :p
thanks for pointing out my obvious stupid error >_<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to

```
SetBookmarkPage(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

You were missing () after Console.ReadLine

Answer (score 4):

There is no overload of `int.Parse` that takes a delegate. It sounds like you wanted to do

```
 int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
```

However, even then you're exposing your program to a potential exception. You should do something like this:

```
 int bookmarkId = 0;
 string info = Console.ReadLine();

 if(!int.TryParse(info, out bookmarkId))
    Console.WriteLine("hey buddy, enter a number next time!");

 SetBookmarkPage(bookmarkId);
```

Comment: +1 for TryParse. It's saved my butt many times when doing mass imports and conversions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call Console.ReadLine:

```
SetBookmarkPage(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

Note the extra `()` in the above.

Your current method is passing a delegate built from the `Console.ReadLine` method, not the result of the method being called.

That being said, if you're reading input from a user, I would strongly recommend using `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`.  User input frequently has errors, and this would let you handle it gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
SetBookmarkPage(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

At the moment it's viewing `Console.ReadLine` as a *method group*, and trying to apply a method group conversion - which will work if you're then using it as an argument for a method taking a `Func<string>` or something similar, but not for a method taking just a string.

You want to *invoke* the method, and then pass the result as an argument. To invoke the method, you need the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant:

```
SetBookmarkPage(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

Notice the parens after `ReadLine`. You are trying to pass a delegate for `ReadLine` instead of the return value.

Answer (score 2):

`Console.ReadLine` is a method, you must invoke it with parenthesis:

```
SetBookmarkPage(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

Without the parenthesis, the compiler thinks it is a method group.